# Multiselect dropdown in Angular js with xeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, x-editable

I am using an AngularJS template in my project. In that having so many controls like textbox, dropdown, datepicker etc.. I want to change the drodown to be multiselect.

I am using xeditable.js from the below ones

http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable

See part of the templated html sample below

```html
<div ng-controller="CriteriaCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <div class="well editable-criteria span12" ng-show="hasKeys()">
    <div class="criteria-loading" ng-show="criterialoading"></div>
    <ul ng-hide="criterialoading">
    <li ng-repeat="criteriaName in criteriaNames" class="{{criteriaName}}">
      <div ng-switch on="criteria[criteriaName].type">
        {{criteria[criteriaName].displayLabel}}:
        <span ng-switch-when="text">
           <a href="#" editable-text="criteria[criteriaName].currentValue"
              onbeforesave="updatetext($data, criteria[criteriaName].name)"
              onshow="hideOtherPopups(criteriaName)">
                 {{ criteria[criteriaName].currentDisplayValue || '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' }}
           </a>
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="dropdown">
           <a href="#" editable-select="criteria[criteriaName].currentValue.currentValue"
              e-ng-options="p.currentValue as p.currentValueLabel for p in possible[criteriaName]"
              onshow="hideOtherPopups(criteriaName)"
              onbeforesave="updatedropdown($data, criteriaName)">
                 {{criteria[criteriaName].currentValueLabel}} 
           </a>
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="date">
           <a href="#" editable-bsdate=" criteria[criteriaName].currentValue"
              e-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" onshow="makedatepicker(criteriaName)"
              onbeforesave="updatedate($data, criteria[criteriaName].name)"
              class="editable-date">
                  {{ ( criteria[criteriaName].currentValue | date:"dd/MM/yyyy") || empty }}
           </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Part of the xeditable for dropdown

```js
angular.module('xeditable').directive('editableSelect', ['editableDirectiveFactory',
  function (editableDirectiveFactory) {
      return editableDirectiveFactory({
          directiveName: 'editableSelect',
          inputTpl: '<select class="xx" multiple="multiple"></select>',
          autosubmit: function () {debugger
              var self = this;
              self.inputEl.bind('change', function () {
                  self.scope.$apply(function () {
                      self.scope.$form.$submit();
                  });
              });
          }
      });
  }]);
```

Because of project complexity, I am not able to provide entire html and script code.

I just need some idea about how I can go further for multi-select dropdown option.

I am using xeditable.js the same way as in the link provided above. Multiple attributes modify the appearance of dropdown. I want something like need to select multiple items and separated by comma.

Can anyone provide the direction for implementing multi-select dropdown in AngularJS with xeditable?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your xeditable.js

```
angular.module('xeditable').directive('editableMultiselect', ['editableDirectiveFactory',
  function (editableDirectiveFactory) {
      return editableDirectiveFactory({
          directiveName: 'editableMultiselect',
          inputTpl: '<select size="6" multiple></select>',
          autosubmit: function () {
              var self = this;
              self.inputEl.bind('change', function () {
                  self.scope.$apply(function () {
                      self.scope.$form.$submit();
                  });
              });
          }             
      });
  }]);
```

In your Form

```
<span editable-multiselect="user.name" e-name="name" e-ng-options="Status.ID as Status.name for Status in Users">
                                {{user.name || 'Not Set'}}
                            </span>
```

Comment: i am not sure what change you made in my existing code. please update more details about your code